# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.8.0

Tags: javascript, php, nginx

All right? I am with 502 bad Gateway problem. When restarting php-fpm it works on the first request, but when it executes a request it is bigger than the 502 bad Gateway problem.
Here are the settings I'm using:

Centos Server, Nginx;

This is nginx.conf

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    #keepalive_timeout   0;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 512M;

    #gzip                on;

fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
           }
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;
    #    root         html;

    #    location / {
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;
    #    root         html;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #    }
    #}
}
```

when I go in the error log

> 14:46:03 [error] 6167#0: *13047 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 177.133.9.36, server: mysoftware.com, request: "POST /alerta/gerarPdf HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "mysoftware.com"

when seeing the error in the nginx log it presents this error,

already tried to execute some changes in ngnix, but I did not even get a success!

follows the changes I made in nginx.conf:

```
  fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

  location / {
            location ~ \ .php $ {
                try_files $ uri = 404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^ (. + \. php) (/.+) $;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $ document_root $ fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
           }
        }
```

Comment: did you check the nginx logs?

Comment: Yes I posted in the post as photo plus the error in the log is this: 14:46:03 [error] 6167#0: *13047 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 177.133.9.36, server: mysoftware.com, request: "POST /alerta/gerarPdf HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "mysoftware.com"

Comment: ahhh yes, try not to post images of text, instead, include the actual text in the post

Comment: I soon adjusted.